# Jsf Error : java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, jsf, openfaces

i am using jsf 2.0 on glassfish 3.0.1 to build an interface to my search engine , when i used Openfaces components on my jsf page and whenever i submit a form i get this error message :

> java.lang.ClassCastException:  [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to
>   com.sun.faces.application.view.StateHolderSaver

i didnt find any help on the web , please what is the problem ? and how to get rid of it ?

thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is known as [JSF issue 1427](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1427). Partial state saving may fail when ajax requests are fired on a page which is been opened by a JSF POST navigation case. There are three solutions, in recommended order:

1. Do not use POST for page-to-page navigation. So replace `<h:commandLink>` by `<h:link>` or `<h:outputLink>`. See also [`h:outputLink` vs `h:commandLink`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink).
2. Implement POST-Redirect-GET pattern. So if you're still using old fashioned `<navigation-case>` in `faces-config.xml`, then add `<redirect/>` entry. Or if you're using implicit navigation outcomes, then add `?faces-redirect=true` query string to the outcome.
3. Configure the problematic pages to utilize full state saving.

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.FULL_STATE_SAVING_VIEW_IDS</param-name>
       <param-value>/pagename.xhtml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

   *(multiple pages can be definied using comma as separator)*

Comment: Maybe it's a type in your 3rd solution, but as you wrote in your blog (http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html) multiple pages should be separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

Download the new version of JSF framework.

See version 2.1.11 !

It's a **problems caused for bug in ajax state request** on internal jsf framework !

For more information please see link http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1845;