# Openfaces pagination not working correctly

Tags: java, jsf-2, pagination, openfaces

I am testing the Openfaces framework. and did a small example through the use of a datatable. The problem is that the pagination is not always working as it supposed to work i.e by clicking the next button, the page displayed is a blank page without records inside the datatable. it manifests itself like this in an on off pattern therefore if I press next the bug would display but on the next click the next set would be diplayed correctly. Please refer to the pics attached below.

clicking the next set button will result in the following repsonse by the pagination.

[image]

re-clicking the next button will make the pagination properly as shown below:

[image]

This sort of pattern would repeat itself along the whole set of records.

This is the code used to produce the datatable:

```
<o:dataTable var="current" value="#{transformer.people}" pageSize="6">
    <f:facet name="below">
        <o:dataTablePaginator id="paginator"/>
    </f:facet>
    <o:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Name" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{current.name}" />
    </o:column>
    <o:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Surname" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{current.surname}" />
    </o:column>
    <o:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Age" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{current.age}" />
    </o:column>
    <o:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Phone Number" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{current.phone}" />
    </o:column>
</o:dataTable>
```

I cant pick out what is missing in my code.

Comment: <<the pagination is not always working as it supposed to work>> then what is the real problem ? Could you populate the page with data ? Be more explicit.

Comment: @soulemanemoumie please refer to the updated problem definition

Comment: the reason is related to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694350/jsf-error-java-lang-classcastexception